# AjaxControlToolKit HTMLEditorExtender - web.config shows warning but it "works" - is this ok?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, ajaxcontroltoolkit, htmleditorextender

I would like to use the HTMLEditorExtender and have followed the following link based on issues with the toolkit and not working properly:

http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/06/25/announcing-the-june-2012-release-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit.aspx

So what I did was install the HTMLAgility pack and set up the references in the project. 
I then followed the instructions in the link above and modified the web.config.
It shows a warning on the "sanitizer" although I've followed the instructions.

[image]

When I run the web application, the control seems to work.

I'm wondering if I should be concerned and try to solve the warning or if i should just let it go because it does work.  OR if someone sees something that I've done incorrectly, I would be grateful if you let me know.

thanks!

Comment: Your IDE does not have the schema to validate the extensions; this is normal and there is no need to be concerned.